# SQL Query linking tables, returning the earliest history from one table with the associated result

Tags: sql, oracle, dense-rank

I have two tables which I need to query. Let's call them table A, and table A_HISTORIES.
Each row from Table A, is linked to multiple rows in A_HISTORIES. What I want to do is to be able to link each row from table A with its earliest history from table A_HISTORIES so something like:-

```
SELECT A.*
       A_HISTORIES.CREATED_DATE
FROM   A, A_HISTORIES
WHERE  A.ID = A_HISTORIES.A_ID
AND    A_HISTORIES.ID = (SELECT  max(id) keep (dense_rank first order by CREATED_DATE) 
                         FROM    A_HISTORIES)
```

However, this will only return the row from A/A_HISTORIES that has the earliest CREATED_DATE. Can anyone help me do this per row in A?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
SELECT A.*
       A_HISTORIES.CREATED_DATE
FROM   A
  INNER JOIN A_HISTORIES ON A.ID = A_HISTORIES.A_ID
  INNER JOIN (SELECT A_ID, MAX(CREATE_DATE) AS max_create_date
              FROM A_HISTORIES
              GROUP BY A_ID) max_hist ON A_HISTORIES.A_ID = max_hist.A_ID 
                                     AND A_HISTORIES.ceate_date = max_create_date
```